# <span></span> gets ignored on IE8, not on mozilla

Tags: html, css, mozilla, internet-explorer-8

I have something like this:

```
 <ul>
   <li>
      <div>
        <div style="display:inline">
          <a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus floatleft "></span></a>
        </div>
        <input   type="checkbox"> <label>good</label>
     </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

the bullet goes above the span on IE8, I would like to make it stay before the span just like in Mozilla, anybody knows how ?

Comment: Can you list your CSS? Combining `display:inline` with `floatleft` looks suspicious already.....

Comment: @zildjohn01 I use css from jquery.ui and a little of my own, but it's nothing really  important just the reset for all tags and it works in mozilla

Comment: What is your expectation? And do you have a DOCTYPE declared? IE8 supports some CSS rules only when it has a doctype defined.

Comment: @Kangkan yes I have the doctype declared

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you have a <div> without an inline style inside the <li> and outside the <div style='display:inline'>
That being so, I would expect the outer div to be formatted as a block rather than being on the same line as the bullet. I'm rather surprised that those other browsers do put it on the same line.

Comment: I agree. From looking at the HTML, I would not expect the bullet next to the span.

Comment: they are on the same line in all browsers, the problem is that because the span has no content the bullet goes over it like it wouldn't exist (the span also has float left, maybe that's important)